# Is it possible to override DependencyProperty to change it's type and add converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, dependency-properties

My model has dates stored as DateTimeOffset. I would like to create a control that inherits from DatePicker and overrides SelectedDate property. I would like that property to be DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime and I would like to handle the conversion from one type to the other inside that custom control.

I know it's possible to create a UserControl with SelectedDate property of DateTimeOffset, put the DatePicker inside that control and bind it's SelectedDate to the new SelectedDate and use converter there. But I would like to avoid that, as it will require for me to re-implement other properties of DatePicker that I might need to use in the future.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You may declare another SelectedDate property, using the `new` keyword. Although probably bad design...

Comment: You can use `object` type for your DP and use `CoerceValueCallback` .

Comment: What's wrong with using a binding with a converter? No need to write a custom user control just to use binding+converter...

Comment: Clemens, you cannot hide DP with new keyword because binding is not done by accessing property directly.

@AnjumSKhan, I've tried overriding metadata for SelectedDate property and handle CoerceValueCallback, but the binding fails before that and the value I get is null.

elgonzo, I would like to avoid logic that requires mandatory converters. Otherwise every developer will have to remember that you cannot just bind DatePicker to model, but you have to use converter.

Comment: @NickSologoub, ah, so you want to share the control with others. I assume you want derive from DatePicker to keep its UI-related functionality. I would suggest the following in this scenario: Derive your control from DatePicker, but keep the SelectedDate property intact. Introduce two new properties, one for the DateTimeOffset, and another for the origin point of the date offset. Whenever either SelectedDate or DateTimeOffset changes, calculate the other property with the help of the origin point. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) This way, your custom DatePicker can simultaneously work with the normal SelectedDate values as well as with offset values.

Comment: @elgonzo, could you maybe post an example as an answer? this sounds like an acceptable solution, although I am not entirely sure what you mean by "origin point" property.

Comment: I wouldn't mind writing a solution, but it would take some time (perhaps over weekend). With "origin point" i meant the following: The DatePicker allows the user to select a point in time, right? But a (date) offset is **not** a point in time, but rather the difference between two points. One of these points is usually a reference point (which isn't necessarily zero), that's what i called "origin point". I should probably have called it "reference date" instead of "origin point", come to think of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to override the property and convert it to another type, but the solution is a little bit tricky. The problem was, that if you hide the original SelectedDate, then new one has not become the changing and vice versa.

Here is your  control:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class OffsetedDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public new DateTimeOffset? SelectedDate
    {
        get { return (DateTimeOffset)GetValue(SelectedDateOffProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDateOffProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateOffProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedDate), typeof(DateTimeOffset?), typeof(OffsetedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null, SelectedDateOffChanged));

    private static void SelectedDateOffChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var odp = d as OffsetedDatePicker;
        if (odp==null) { return; }          
        (d as DatePicker).SelectedDate = odp.SelectedDate.HasValue ? odp.SelectedDate.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null;
    }

    public OffsetedDatePicker()
    {
        SelectedDateChanged += OffsetedDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged;
    }

    private void OffsetedDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime? newDate = null;
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            newDate = (DateTime)e.AddedItems[0];
        }
        SetValue(SelectedDateOffProperty, newDate.HasValue ? new DateTimeOffset(newDate.Value) : (DateTimeOffset?)null);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:OffsetedDatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=YourVMDateTimeOffsetProp, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```